# How to get the assembly name(not qualified name) from type(only assembly name without version or culture or publickeyToken) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

How to get the assembly name (only name ) without namespace or culture or public key token;typeof (MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName ---> give me the fully qualified name and i want only the assembly name not the qualified name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get [simple name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the assembly, try

```
typeof(MyClass).Assembly.GetName().Name
```